# svnserve refuses to authorize any writes to a local svn:// repository

Tags: svn, authorization, svnserve

I'm using a very basic setup for svnserve to provide an svn:// repository to my local network.
Here's my setup, as well as my problem: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xx7v8zzt)

Each time I modify the auth details I restart the server entirely using killall svnserve.

I've tried passwd with both : and = forms, i've added an authz-db line with a simple authz config of

```
[/]
* = rw
```

all with no luck. Any suggestions?

My svnserve version is 1.6.12 with Cyrus SASL

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't use SASL at all - consult with [Better Security with SASL](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html) section
2. You can try to start it without --username option and ask the server to request auth. data, if needed - read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.tour.initial.different-user)
3. If svn://localhost/ isn't your repository (you didn't show how you started svnserve, but *I suppose*, you have wrong URL for the repo), you can't use svn commands on URL

> Assuming your repository is located in c:\repos\TestRepo, and your
>   server is called localhost, enter:
>
> `svn://localhost/repos/TestRepo`
>
> when prompted by the repo browser

and later

> Using the previous test as a guide, svnserve would now run as:
>
> ```
> svnserve.exe --daemon --root c:\repos
> ```
>
> And in TortoiseSVN our repo-browser URL is now shortened to:
>
> ```
> svn://localhost/TestRepo
> ```

**Resume:**

your config is good, your understanding of processes and configurations is bad

Comment: My svnserve command has the options -d and -r. Are these options the same thing as --daemon and --root options?